# do we need to set iOS deployment target to 13.0?

Tags: ios, xcode

As per apple latest requirements 2020 April all apps should have base SDK 13.0 does this mean we need to set deployment target to 13.0 or just build app using Xcode 11.x and leave existing deployment target?

My current app min target is 11.0 but still working on iOS 13.0 devices? Do I need to change any thing for future releases.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

> As per apple latest requirements 2020 April all apps should have base
>   SDK 13.0 does this mean we need to set deployment target to 13.0 or
>   just build app using Xcode 11.x and leave existing deployment target?

The latter. The keyword is "SDK". You just need to use/build your application using the SDK. You may set your deployment target to as low as you can or whatever your current Xcode allows the lowest/oldest.

> My current app min target is 11.0 but still working on iOS 13.0
>   devices? Do I need to change any thing for future releases.

No. Your minimum target is literally the minimum target. It means that any iOS version below that target won't be able to install/run your application. But any higher iOS version will be definitely supported.

Comment: @matt not sure I understand. I thought that if the target version of your app is iOS 11, you can't use iOS 13 code.